# iOS7 JavaScriptCore framework compatibility

Tags: ios, ios7, compatibility, javascriptcore

I am building an iOS app. I would like it to be compatible with all iOS versions. I will use the JavaScriptCore framework introduced in iOS7. Does it mean that my only deployment target will be iOS 7 an later? Will I be able to run this app on iOS6 for example or earlier versions of the iOS.

Thank you

Comment: If it is only available in iOS7 and later then no you can't use it for iOS 6 and below development.

Answer (score 1):

The framework was only introduced in iOS7, so you will have to use other frameworks to have downwards compatibility.

I don't work with iOS development, but if the framework was introduced in iOS7, it wouldn't work as you suggest it possibly could.